# Spring Integration 4 - samples - Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-integration

Having watched the Spring Integration overview presentation and I'd like to try out the Spring Integration sample projects. We use `Gradle` instead of `Maven`. I'm really confused by all the pom.xml files throughout the sample projects. How much is just a 'noise' and how much is critical for the project be built well? Is the project convertible to `Gradle`, or is `Maven` unavoidable?

Comment: Out of topic. Is your name really `Martin Flower`?

Comment: : ) Yes, my name is indeed Martin Flower

Comment: Oh, Sorry! You aren't **Martin Fowler** ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually current version of Spring Integration Samples Project has been converted to the Gradle: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples

Comment: Thanks, was converted just a few days ago - another lesson for me to  pull first, ask questions second!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both `Maven` and `Gradle` have the same functionality except that `Maven` uses XML and `Gradle` uses custom DSL based on `Groovy`. But it's really obvious that the future belongs to `Gradle`.